# custom 404 page not work Apache/2.4.51 if missing is in a virtual subdirectory (Debian)

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, 404, apache2

this is my first question here, I hope to find a solution.
I have a problem with page 404 when the missing page is in a sub "virtual" directory, is used to pass a value to php, in DocumentRoot not exist a directory "de" (for example) for this reason I cannot create a 404 page for each directory.
If the url is [www.example.com/wrongpage.html](http://www.example.com/wrongpage.html) works fine shows the custom 404 page thanks to **ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php** in the htaccess.

If the url is [www.example.comm/**de**/wrongpage.html](http://www.example.comm/**de**/wrongpage.html) it shows "File not found." and it doesn't load my 404 custom page.

I tried adding "ProxyErrorOverride On" to apache.conf no result even in virtualhost no result. The server has no particular configuration, everything is by default. Since I am using php-fpm before I used php so many configurations are inherited.

Here are the htacces and the virtualhost

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
 RewriteRule .* . [F,L]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html         $2.php?ln=$1 [L]
 
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

It doesn't work either by putting an absolute URL

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404page.php
```

And part of virtualhost

```
DocumentRoot /www/example.com/
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Directory /www/example.com/>
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html         $2.php?ln=$1 [L]
> ```

When you request `/de/wrongpage.html` the above rule "unconditionally" rewrites the request to `wrongpage.php?ln=de` and it's this that is probably triggering the system "File not found" message. (`.php` requests are perhaps proxied to a CGI backend?)

You could instead first check that the corresponding `.php` file exists before rewriting.

Also, do you need to check whether the requested `.html` file exists? You've stated that the language directory is virtual, so could this ever map to a real file? Likewise, the directory check would also seem redundant. (Presumably you don't have directories that contain `.html` anyway?)

Your regex that matches the 2-character(?) language code would also seem too general - you are matching "anything"? Is `/something/foo.html` a valid request? The regex should be as specific as necessary. If your language code is always two lowercase letters then match just that. eg. `[a-z]{2}`.

And you are missing the end-of-string anchor (ie. `$` after `.html`), so this also matches `/foo/bar.html<anything>` - potentially resulting in duplicate content.

Try the rule like this instead:

```
# Rewrite to PHP file if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)\.html$ $2.php?ln=$1 [L]
```

You don't need the `RewriteBase` directive here and your user-agent block could be tidied (use a *hyphen* to indicate no substitution). (The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required - unless these directives are *optional*?)

So, your complete `.htaccess` file should look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Rewrite to PHP file if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)\.html$ $2.php?ln=$1 [L]
```

---

> ```
> Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

Are you sure you want to enable MultiViews?

Comment: thanks for the answer and the explanations it was enough to add  
`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f` before `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)\.html$ $2.php?ln=$1 [L]`.
I removed MultiViews